# $(this).text() vs $(this).attr("innerText") in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a nub in jQuery and javascript in general, so this must be a beginners question.

This line works for me, foo is not empty:

```
var foo = $("#hello").find("option").filter (function(){return $(this).text() == "BAR";});
```

This one in the same spot doesn't (foo undefined):

```
var foo = $("#hello").find("option").filter (function(){return $(this).attr("innerText") == "BAR";});
```

The only difference is using .text() vs .attr("innerText"). Why the latter doesn't work for me?

Comment: how is your HTML? Post it, please.

Comment: Do you have an attribute called `innerText`? Also, does `#hello` without quotes in your selector really work? And the quotes are `BAR` are not the same quotes.

Comment: Because innerText is a Microsoft concoction?

Comment: As tymeJS mentioned, probably the element doesn't have an attribute innerText. jQuery's text() method encapsulate the .innerText from vanilla js, such as .html() encaspulate innerHTML.

Comment: `innerText` is a property, you'd get that with jQuery's `prop()` method, but why would you when you can use `text()` instead, which is cross browser (innerText is not)

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the correction; the idea was correct in my head, the wording was not.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the lack of "" around #hello selector and different quotes around BAR. Both were the result of my trying to beatify the code before posting. I fixed that. The problem is definitely not due to that.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, you're right, text() worked, but I spent too much time trying to make innerText to work, so I couldn't just let it go :)

Comment: @CBroe I should have said that I use Chrome. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.attr()` finds HTML attributes attached to the DOM element, it's not looking for the DOM element's JavaScript attributes like `innerHTML` or `innerText`. To find such attributes, you need to access the DOM element inside the jQuery object that the selector returns, or in this case, the `this` reference itself, such as:

```
var foo = $('#hello').find("option").filter (function(){return this.innerText == “BAR";});
```

As pointed out by others, this is not advised since it can lead to unexpected behavior and it's also not cross-browser compatible. Just use `.text()` instead.

Comment: (It should be noted that using `innerText` is still not advisable.)

Answer (score 1):

`.attr()` is looking for the attribute `innerText` on the node. It will give you `undefined` except if you node look like that :

```
<div innerText="test"></div>
```

Maybe your are mixing yourself with `.prop('innerText')` which get the property `innerText` of the node. That is the same as `.text()` except that `.text()` is safer since jQuery counter compatibility issues..

If you are interested by how jQuery get the text no matter which browser you are, here [the relevant code](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L1886)